# Download html page locally in phonegap app

Tags: cordova

I made a phonegap app in html/css/js.
I also made a web page using exactly the same html/css/js files for the phonegap app.

The only difference is that the phonegap app is offline and the web page is online.
You can see where I'm going with this.

I have a button called update. When clicked, I want it to download the online web page. Then replace the offline file with the downloaded file.

I can probably do this in xcode. But how can it be done in phonegap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an event to your button like this:

```
document.location = "index.html"
```

This will reload your webview. You must set the cache correctly so new files will be updated (HTML5 cache specification):

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_app_cache.asp